# How to implement multi dependency injection decorator with autofac

Tags: c#, decorator, autofac, composite

I want to call `MessageStore` class with IOC container autofac.

How can I register this decorator and composite pattern with the latest version of autofac?

This code combined composite and decorator pattern and pay attention SOLID Principal.

I'm Confusing about that. My question is, this code how to defined with autofac

`var fileStore = new FileStore(new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/file"))); var cacheStore = new CacheStore(fileStore, fileStore); var logStore = new LogStore(cacheStore, cacheStore); var messageStore = new MessageStore(logStore, logStore); messageStore.Save(12, "Hello");`

```
public class FileStore :  IFileLocator, IStoreWriter,IStoreReader
{
    private readonly DirectoryInfo _workingDirectory;

    public FileStore(DirectoryInfo workDirectory)
    {
        if (workDirectory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("workDirectory");

        if (!workDirectory.Exists)
            throw new ArgumentException("Directory not found", "workDirectory");

        _workingDirectory = workDirectory;
    }

    public virtual void Save(int id, string message)
    {
        var path = GetFileInfo(id).FullName;
        File.WriteAllText(path, message);
    }

    public virtual Maybe<string> Read(int id)
    {
        var file = GetFileInfo(id);

        if (!file.Exists)
            return new Maybe<string>();

        var path = file.FullName;
        return new Maybe<string>(File.ReadAllText(path));
    }

    public virtual FileInfo GetFileInfo(int id)
    {
        return new FileInfo(
            Path.Combine(_workingDirectory.FullName, id + ".txt"));
    }
}

public class CacheStore : IStoreWriter, IStoreReader
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, Maybe<string>> _cache;
    private readonly IStoreWriter _writer;
    private readonly IStoreReader _reader;

    public CacheStore(IStoreWriter writer, IStoreReader reader)
    {
        _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Maybe<string>>();
        _writer = writer;
        _reader = reader;
    }

    public virtual void Save(int id, string message)
    {
        _writer.Save(id, message);
        var m = new Maybe<string>(message);
        _cache.AddOrUpdate(id, m, (i, s) => m);
    }

    public virtual Maybe<string> Read(int id)
    {
        Maybe<string> retVal;
        if (_cache.TryGetValue(id, out retVal))
            return retVal;

        retVal = _reader.Read(id);
        if (retVal.Any())
            _cache.AddOrUpdate(id, retVal, (i, s) => retVal);
        return retVal;
    }
}

public class LogStore :  IStoreWriter, IStoreReader
{
    private readonly IStoreWriter _writer;
    private readonly IStoreReader _reader;
    public LogStore(IStoreWriter writer, IStoreReader reader)
    {
        _writer = writer;
        _reader = reader;
    }
    public void Save(int id, string message)
    {
        Log.Information("Saving message {id}.", id);
        _writer.Save(id, message);
        Log.Information("Saved message {id}.", id);
    }

    public Maybe<string> Read(int id)
    {
        Log.Debug("Reading message {id}.", id);
        var retVal = _reader.Read(id);
        if (retVal.Any())
            Log.Debug("Returning message {id}.", id);
        else
            Log.Debug("No message {id} found.", id);
        return retVal;
    }

}

 public class MessageStore
{
    private readonly IStoreWriter _writer;
    private readonly IStoreReader _reader;
    public MessageStore(IStoreWriter writer, IStoreReader reader)
    {
        if (writer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
        _writer = writer;
        _reader = reader;
    }

    public void Save(int id, string message)
    {
        _writer.Save(id, message);
    }

    public Maybe<string> Read(int id)
    {
        return _reader.Read(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement this yourself? What did you get stuck on? There is some good information about decorators on the Autofac documentation site (http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html) and in this blog post (http://nblumhardt.com/2010/04/lightweight-adaptation-%E2%80%93-coming-soon/). I also think you need to be clearer about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't know. but I'm Confusing about that. My question is, this code how to defined with autofac `var fileStore = new FileStore(new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/file")));
            var cacheStore = new CacheStore(fileStore, fileStore);
            var logStore = new LogStore(cacheStore, cacheStore);
            var messageStore = new MessageStore(logStore, logStore);
            messageStore.Save(12, "Hello");`

Comment: Can you update your question to include this information rather than leaving it down here as a comment? It will help to understand what's actually being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that all your stores implement and use both `IStoreReader` and `IStoreWriter` you could make things simpler by combining them into a single `IStore` interface. This could be a single interface defining a `Save` and `Read` method, or it could inherit from the existing `IStoreReader` and `IStoreWriter` interfaces if required.

You can then register your `FileStore` - which appears to be the primary implementation - as a keyed service. Then use `RegisterDecorator` to register the cache and log decorators. Finally, register the `MessageStore` and resolve the service that doesn't have a key, which will be the outermost decorator.

```
builder.Register(f => new FileStore(new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/file"))))
    .Keyed<IStore>("file");

builder.RegisterDecorator<IStore>(
    (c, inner) => new CacheStore(inner), fromKey: "file", toKey: "cache");

builder.RegisterDecorator<IStore>(
    (c, inner) => new LogStore(inner), fromKey: "cache", toKey: null);

builder.Register(c => new MessageStore(c.Resolve<IStore>()));
```

I'm sure the API around decorators can be improved and this is definitely something I intend to look at doing soon.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alex. But I solved with below code since I don't want create `IStore`. do you think about my discussion?

```
builder.Register(f => new FileStore(new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/file")))) 
            .Named<IStoreWriter>("F-writer").Named<IStoreReader>("F-reader");
        builder.Register( 
            c => new CacheStore(c.ResolveNamed<IStoreWriter>("F-writer"), c.ResolveNamed<IStoreReader>("F-reader"))) 
            .Named<IStoreWriter>("C-writer").Named<IStoreReader>("C-reader"); 

        builder.Register( 
            c => new LogStore(c.ResolveNamed<IStoreWriter>("C-writer"), c.ResolveNamed<IStoreReader>("C-reader"))) 
            .Named<IStoreWriter>("L-writer").Named<IStoreReader>("L-reader"); 

        builder.Register( 
            c => 
                new MessageStore(c.ResolveNamed<IStoreWriter>("L-writer"), c.ResolveNamed<IStoreReader>("L-reader")));
```